# how to read the whole json file as one object in aws glue

Tags: json, aws-glue

Based on AWS document, AWG glue can read the json like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-json-home.html
If the json file is like this,

```
{"good": 2, "bad"; 1}
```

I want to read the whole json file as one object, what is right way to do it?

```
ynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://s3path"]},
    format="json",
    format_options={
        "jsonPath": "$",
        "multiline": True,
        # "optimizePerformance": True, -> not compatible with jsonPath, multiline
    }
)
```

Do I need to specify jsonPath as "$" or "$*"?